# HTML5 Canvas - Popping popcorn animation / random images?

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Maybe I am asking the wrong question completely. I have read quite a bit and seen quite a bit of HTML 5 capabilities; however, I have not yet had time to sit down and really start utilizing any of it yet :(, but hope to soon.

Anyway, I was curious if I could do the following with HTML5 and how to begin to implement it. Or, if this does not work, then how can I make it work?

I have a popcorn image (1 piece of popped popcorn that is).

I wanted to create a canvas and on a button click, start a chain of this image being randomly "popped" onto the canvas, slowly at first then gaining speed until such time there should be a stopping point.

Anyone who has popped popcorn can understand what I am looking to do here.

Is this possible to do easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've popped popcorn and, yep, you can do this. Load the popcorn image by creating an `Image` object and setting its `src` attribute. Use the image's `onload` property to start the animation. Given the animation's duration *k*, use a sine curve, `sin(x/(k/π))`, to calculate the number of kernels to show per frame.

Here's one way of doing it, demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/uyk63/8/

```
var IMAGE_URL = 'http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/959519/2/stock-photo-959519-isolated-single-popcorn.jpg';
var DURATION = 10 * 1000, FRAMES = 30, KERNELS = 10;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var frame = 0,
    start = new Date().getTime(),
    image = new Image;
image.src = IMAGE_URL;
image.onload = function() {

    function pop() {
        ctx.drawImage(image,
            Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
            100, 50);
    }

    // A little overcomplicated. You could probably do this in a single loop.
    // (It's late and I'm tired, though. Sorry.)
    function animate() {
        var i, delay,
            count = Math.floor(Math.sin(frame / (FRAMES / Math.PI)) * KERNELS);  
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            delay = (DURATION / FRAMES) / count * i;
            setTimeout(pop, delay);
        }
        if (++frame < FRAMES) {
            setTimeout(animate, DURATION / FRAMES);
        }
    }
    animate();

};
```